# Second API documentation using Swagger with JAVA

Tags: java, swagger

I need to make a second API documentation with the code that already exists... I work on a system that currently has an API, but we're going to make a second API available to third parties (integration API) I have no idea how to do this, because everything is overwritten.

I want the existing documentation to remain the same, but create a second one with some existing endpoints and block others. I need help with this because I don't know where to look anymore.

I've tried a lot of things but nothing has worked!